# getting an error alert in lightning - Typeerror: p.get is not a function in js controller (here 'p' is a var)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

mixerComponent.cmp

```
    <aura:component controller="schedulingController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<ltng:require styles="/resource/LightningDesignSystem/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/>
<aura:attribute name="prodctlg" type="c.Product_Catalog__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="newLocation1" type="c.Location__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Location__c','Name': 'Mixer 1','Product_Catalog__c': '','Total_No_Of_Batch__c': 0,'No_Of_Batch_In_Process__c': 0}"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getMixerList}"/>
<div class="slds-col slds-no-flex slds-align-bottom">
              <div class="slds-button-group">
                  <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick=" {!c.showModal1}">Add</button>
              </div>
</div>
<div aria-hidden="false" id="newLocationId1" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-modal--large slds-fade-in-open" style="display:none;margin-left:300px;">
<div class="slds-modal__container">
<div class="slds-modal__header"><h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Schedule Product to Process</h2>
<button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close" onclick="{!c.showModalBox1}">
<c:svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large" xlinkHref="/resource/LightningDesignSystem/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close" ariaHidden="true"/>
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="slds-modal__content">
<div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<ui:inputText aura:id="locationname" label="Location Name"
class="slds-input"
labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
value="{!v.newLocation1.Name}"
required="true"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="prods" label="Product" change="{!c.onSelectChange}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.prodctlg}" var="product">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!product.Name}" label="{!product.Name}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
<ui:inputText aura:id="productId" label="Product Id" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!v.newLocation1.Product_Catalog__c}" required="true"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<ui:inputText aura:id="noOfBatch" label="No of Batch" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!v.newLocation1.Total_No_Of_Batch__c}" required="true"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-modal__footer">
<div class="slds-x-small-buttons--horizontal">
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.showModalBox1}" >Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

mixerComponentController.js

```
({  
getMixerList: function(component, event, helper){

     helper.getProductCatalogue(component);


},
onSelectChange:function(component, event, helper) {
var p = component.find('prods');
var selectedValue = p.get("v.value");
var selectedId= component.find('productId');
selectedId.set("v.value",selectedValue.toString());
console.log('++++++'+selectedValue);
},

showModal1 : function(component, event, helper) {
document.getElementById("newLocationId1").style.display = "block";
},
})
```

mixerComponentHelper.js

```
({
getProductCatalogue: function(component) {
var action = component.get("c.getProductCatalogue");

//Set up the callback
var self = this;
action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
    component.set("v.prodctlg", actionResult.getReturnValue());            
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

schedulingController.cls

```
public with sharing class schedulingController{
@AuraEnabled 
public static List<Product_Catalog__c> getProductCatalogue() {
List<Product_Catalog__c> prdctlg = new List<Product_Catalog__c>();
prdctlg = [select id,name from Product_Catalog__c];
return prdctlg;

}
```

Now, when I hit the **Add** button the **showModal1** gets called and the modal box with id **newLocationId1** gets open.

After this when I change the value in **ui:inputSelect**

with **aura:id = prods**  the **onSelectChange** method get called and throws this error alert

[image]

I have no idea why this is happenning. I have tried a lot to fix the issue. But all in vain..Any help!!

Comment: Instead of `var p = component.find('prods');
var selectedValue = p.get("v.value");`, can try this `var selVal  = event.getSource().get("v.value");` let me know?

Comment: var selectedValue = event.getSource().get("v.value");
         var selectedId= component.find('productId');
         selectedId.set("v.value",selectedValue.toString());
Now I am getting selectedId.set is not a function
@Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var p = component.find('prods'); var selectedValue = p.get("v.value");`.

You can directly get the component firing the event using: `event.getSource()`
So replace above statement with below:

`var selVal = event.getSource().get("v.value");`

With that said, instead of setting the below `<ui:inputText/>` using component.find() followed by component.set():

```
 <ui:inputText aura:id="productId" label="Product Id" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!v.newLocation1.Product_Catalog__c}" required="true"/>
```

I would do this, since you are already binding the `ui:inputText`'s value to an aura:attribute.

```
onSelectChange:function(component, event, helper) {
    var selVal = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    component.set('v.newLocation1.Product_Catalog__c',selVal);
},
```